# Trying to launch windows after uninstalling LXLE: file /boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found

Tags: grubrescue

I needed to uninstall LXLE (a Linux distro) on my laptop and use just Windows 7 instead. I read somewhere that going into the root terminal and typing `sudo apt-cache show lxde` and then deleting the files shown would uninstall LXLE, so I did that and rebooted. But now whenever I try to boot, I get the following error upon startup: `file /boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` not found.

Now I need to know how I can get my computer to just launch Windows instead when I boot. Typing into the `grub rescue>` (whatever that is...) does nothing. Please use layman's terms, I have no experience with this kind of stuff and won't understand a bunch of technical jargon.

Comment: @mudit: please review my edits...  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot to a Windows recovery disk (any recovery/installation disk or USB, including the free Windows 10 Technical Preview one will do).

Instead of using "Install Now", use "Repair your computer". Then go to Troubleshoot>Command prompt. Type:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Your computer should now be fixed.

Comment: I put the windows 10 development preview iso file onto a flash drive and selected to boot my computer from it, but now my computer simply says "Boot error". This is the same way I installed LXLE on my system in the first place and it worked fine, which is strange.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work and now everything is back to normal. Thanks a lot!